# Unable to use QtColorComboxBox with qt.4.3.3

Tags: qt

I have qt.4.3.3 version of QT and I am trying to use QtColorComboxBox .It's not part of the official Qt package, but is in the QtSolutions. since it is not part of Qt package , could you let me know how can I use it for my project work .

Also is there any any widget in QT 4.3.3 which has the same functionality of QtColorComboxBox .

The reference for QtColorComboxBox is as follows https://github.com/liangqi/qt-solutions